# ProcessBuilder throws exception: Arguement contains =

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to create filesystem for the raid drives on linux, using java.

I run into following problem when i try to execute following command using ProcessBuilder.

> Process '[/usr/bin/sudo, /sbin/mkfs.ext4, /dev/md0, -m 1, -O
>   uninit_bg, -E lazy_itable_init=1]' stderr dump: mke2fs 1.42.3
>   (14-May-2012)
>
> Bad option(s) specified:  lazy_   _init
>
> Extended options are separated by commas, and may take an argument
>   which
>           is set off by an equals ('=') sign.
>
> Valid extended options are:
>           stride=
>           stripe-width=
>           resize=
>           lazy_itable_init=<0 to disable, 1 to enable>
>           lazy_journal_init=<0 to disable, 1 to enable>
>           test_fs
>           discard
>           nodiscard
>           quotatype=

My ProcessBuilder object looks like this

```
mkfs("ext4", "/dev/md0", "-m 1", "-O uninit_bg", "-E lazy_itable_init=1")

public void mkfs(String filesystem, String devicename, String... options) {
mkfsCommand.add(SUDO_CMD);
if(fileSystemType.equals("xfs")){
            mkfsCommand.add("/sbin/mkfs.xfs");
        } else if (fileSystemType.equals("ext4")) {
            mkfsCommand.add("/sbin/mkfs.ext4");
        }

        mkfsCommand.add(deviceName);
        for (String option:options) {
            mkfsCommand.add(option);
        }
List<String> mkfsCommand = Lists.newLinkedList();
Exec.exec(ProcessBuilder(mkfsCommand))
}
```

Exec.exec is a library i am using to execute system commands. i can't change it, but here is the snippet of what it does.

```
public String exec(ProcessBuilder pb) {
    String cmdString = Arrays.deepToString(pb.command().toArray(new String[0]));
        int retval = 0;
        Process p = null;
        String output = "";
        if(shouldLog) {
            logger.debug("in exec: " + cmdString);
        }
        String error = null;
        try {
            p = pb.start();
            if (executionDeadline != null) {
                Thread durationEnforcer = new DurationEnforcer(executionDeadline, p);
                durationEnforcer.start();
            }
            Future<String> futureErr = null;
            if (!pb.redirectErrorStream()) {
                futureErr = SingleExecutor.submit(new StreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            }
            StreamReader outputReader = new StreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            output = outputReader.call();
            retval = p.waitFor();

            if (futureErr != null) {
                error = futureErr.get();
            }
            if (error != null && !error.isEmpty()) {
                if(shouldLog) {
                    logger.warn("Process '" + cmdString + "' stderr dump:\n" + error);
                }
            }
            this.stdOutput = output;
            this.stdError = error;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("exec failed: " + e + "\nstdout:\n" + output);
            throw new RuntimeException("exec failed: ", e);
        } finally {
            StreamHelper.closeStreamsAndDestroy(p);
        }
        if (retval != 0) {
            String msg = "exec failed with " + retval + ": " + cmdString;
            if(shouldLog) {
                logger.warn(msg + "\nstdout:\n" + output);
            }
            throw new ExecException(error, cmdString, retval, output);
        }
        if(shouldLog) {
            logger.debug("finished exec: " + cmdString);
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error. I suspect that -E lazy_itable_init=1 is not being passed correctly to the Processbuilder. Any thoughts on whats happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that it's you command `String`....

```
"ext4", "/dev/md0", "-m 1", "-O uninit_bg", "-E lazy_itable_init=1"
```

This is basically saying to `ext4`, that you have 4 arguments...

- `/dev/md0`
- `-m 1`
- `-O uninit_bg`
- `-E lazy_itable_init=1`

When I suspect it actually wants 7.

- `/dev/md0`
- `-m`
- `1`
- `-O`
- `uninit_bg`
- `-E`
- `lazy_itable_init=1`

Or simular...

Instead, try using something like...

```
"ext4", "/dev/md0", "-m", "1", "-O", "uninit_bg", "-E", "lazy_itable_init=1"
```

Each `String` element you pass `ProcessBuilder` will be treated as a separate argument to the command (each argument being separated by a space on the command line, for example).

This makes `ProcessBuilder` very powerful, as it can deal with command arguments that actually do contain spaces, without all the messing about with escaping quotes :P